# Is there a Central limit theorem for max

Tags: statistics

I have multiple IID (bigger then 0) of unknown distribution and I get the max of them as a result of my calculation.

Can I say that the max also have certain gaussian shape distribution?
If not what is the distribution of the result?

I saw this [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/728406/central-limit-theorem-for-a-product) which describe the result of IID product in a log-normal distribution. but as far as I understand this is not the same as max.

I tried to run a simulation in MATLAB with 1000*1000 uniform IID in range 1000 and got that the max of each column is **not** distibuted randomlly but getting close to 1000.
here is the code:

```
r = randi(1000,[1000,1000]);
mxR = max(r);
figure;
hist(mxR);
```

After that I tried some other non - caped distribution (normal dist. with \mu = 5000 and \sigma = 500) and I got something similar tolog-normal dist.
[distribution result of max IID (normal)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DxC5i.png)

here is the code:

```
r = random('Normal',5000,500,[10000,10000]);
mxR = max(r);
figure;
hist(mxR);
```

Is there a rule or a theorem regarding this?

thanks for your help!!
(If you think this is interesting (or not) please let me know)

Comment: Hello! Perhaps this is of help: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/18433/how-do-you-calculate-the-probability-density-function-of-the-maximum-of-a-sample
Have you researched any other material?

Comment: thanks for the replay! I'll look into it. I tried and found on google some min-max normal distribution papers which is   not relevant to me. also my real distribution is not "normal dist." but something else

Comment: @FedePoncio the reference was indeed very helpful. thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it’s called the [Generalized Extreme Value Distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalized_extreme_value_distribution) .

The conditions of convergence are given by the [Fisher-Tippet-Gnedenko Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Tippett%E2%80%93Gnedenko_theorem).

Basically, it says the distribution of an extreme order statistic (max,min) of an iid sample can converge to one of three distributions.